# Plot data using loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, ggplot2

**I want to make a plot of the Daily Streamflow in each Station and save it in png format.** I want a separate png for each station, something like the image below:

[image]

I have a list with the data frame for each station, as shown in the figure below:
[image]

I am trying using the following code, but it is not working because R aborted, I am not sure if it is because of the quantity of data:

```
for (i in 1:length(listDF2)) 
{
  df1 <- as.data.frame(listDF2[[i]])
  df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
  temp_plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = day, y = DailyMeanStreamflow, colour=Station)) +
  geom_line(size = 1)  + 
  geom_point(size=1.5, shape=21, fill="white") + 
  facet_wrap(~ month, ncol = 3) +
  labs(title = "Daily Mean Streamflow",
       subtitle = "Data plotted by month",
       y = "Daily Mean Streamflow [m3/s]", x="Days") + 
  scale_y_continuous (breaks=seq(0,max(df1$DailyMeanStreamflow, na.rm=TRUE),by=1500)) +
  scale_x_continuous (breaks=seq(1,max(df1$day),by=1)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=9))

  print(temp_plot)

  name4<- paste("DailyStreamflow_byMonth","_", siteNumber[i], ".png", sep="")
  ggsave(temp_plot,filename = name4,width=22,height=11,units="in",dpi=500)

  #while (!is.null(dev.list()))
  dev.off()
}
```

I have also a "big" data frame with the data for each station one after the other. This data frame is useful when I want to apply functions like `data_frame %>% group_by(station) %>% summarise(...)`

**Any idea in how to make the plots for each station? Is it better to use the list or the "big" data frame for this purpose?**

Comment: Could you do something using the `map` function in `purrr`? https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the problem in your workflow occures. It is quite hard to help you, as we have not [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also I am not sure if you just want to produce your plots in a loop or if you (also) want to put them together in one visualization?

Anyways ... I tried to give you a starting point ... maybe this will help?

```
"%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"

df_list <- list(
  A=dplyr::tibble(ID=1:10,
                  x=rnorm(10),
                  y=rnorm(10)),
  B=dplyr::tibble(ID=1:10,
                  x=rnorm(10),
                  y=rnorm(10)),
  C=dplyr::tibble(ID=1:10,
                  x=rnorm(10),
                  y=rnorm(10)),
  D=dplyr::tibble(ID=1:10,
                  x=rnorm(10),
                  y=rnorm(10)))

# Lapply approach
lapply(df_list, function(dat){
  p <- dat %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point()
  print(p)
})

# Loop approach
for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
  p <- df_list[[i]] %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point()
  print(p)
  fname <- paste("test","_", i, ".png", sep="")
  ggsave(p,
         filename=fname,
         width=22,
         height=11,
         units="in",
         dpi=500)
}
```